# Как установить PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pycharm

Значит, открываю я консоль и ввожу 
pip install PyOpenGL 
Все устанавливается, но когда я ввожу `import OpenGL`, Pycharm выделяет красным и пишет, что такого модуля нет, и, когда я запускаю программу, выдаёт ошибку: 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL'` 
Что мне делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: pip install pyopengl

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё работает.